# Subscribing to IOT topic in Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, iot

I'm trying to subscribe to a topic via my Android application. Even though it connects successfully subscription fails. As soon as I perform subscription call, IOT connectivity fails and gives an error log as stated below. Want to Know where have I done any wrong coding ?
All the resources of IOT policy is given due to testing purposes to find a clue.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
   {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:*",
      "Resource": "*"
   }
 ]
}
```

I referred AWS-amplify for my development.
https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/android/pubsub

1 .Connecting to IOT

```
    private var mAWSMobileClient : AWSMobileClient = AWSMobileClient.getInstance()
    private lateinit var mIotDataManager: AWSIotMqttManager
    private lateinit var mAttachedPolicyReq: AttachPolicyRequest
    private lateinit var mAwsIOTClient: AWSIotClient
    private lateinit var mAwsCredentials: AWSCredentials

 private fun connectToIOT() {
        Thread(Runnable {
            var mDeviceIdentity = Settings.Secure.getString(this.contentResolver, Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID)

            mIotDataManager = AWSIotMqttManager(mDeviceIdentity, <iot endpoint>)
            mIotDataManager.keepAlive = 50
            mIotDataManager.isAutoReconnect = false
            mIotDataManager.connectionStabilityTime = 100

            mAwsCredentials = mAWSMobileClient.awsCredentials
            mAwsIOTClient = AWSIotClient(mAWSMobileClient)
            mAwsIOTClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTHEAST_2))

            mAttachedPolicyReq = AttachPolicyRequest()
            mAttachedPolicyReq.policyName = "test_policy"
            mAttachedPolicyReq.target = mAWSMobileClient.identityId
            mAwsIOTClient.attachPolicy(mAttachedPolicyReq)

            try {
                mIotDataManager.connect(mAWSMobileClient, object : AWSIotMqttClientStatusCallback {
                    override fun onStatusChanged(
                        status: AWSIotMqttClientStatusCallback.AWSIotMqttClientStatus?,
                        throwable: Throwable?
                    ) {
                        when (status) {
                            AWSIotMqttClientStatusCallback.AWSIotMqttClientStatus.ConnectionLost -> {}

                            AWSIotMqttClientStatusCallback.AWSIotMqttClientStatus.Connected -> {}

                            AWSIotMqttClientStatusCallback.AWSIotMqttClientStatus.Connecting -> {}

                            AWSIotMqttClientStatusCallback.AWSIotMqttClientStatus.Reconnecting -> {}

                        else -> {

                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("IOT Data Manager Connection Errror : $e")
        }
    }).start()
}
```

2. Subscription Method

   ```
   fun subscribeToThing() {
           if(mConnected) {
               Thread(Runnable {
                   mThingsName = "$mThingsName/shadow/get/accepted"
                   var message: String? = null
                   try {
                       mIotDataManager.subscribeToTopic(
                           mThingsName,
                           AWSIotMqttQos.QOS1,
                           object : AWSIotMqttNewMessageCallback {
                               override fun onMessageArrived(topic: String?, data: ByteArray?) {

                                   try {
                                       message = String(data!!, Charsets.UTF_8)
                                   } catch (e: UnsupportedEncodingException) {
                                       Log.d("Unsupported Encoding error :$e")
                                   }
                               }
                           })
                   } catch (e: Exception) {
                       Log.d("Subscription error :$e")
                   }
           }).start()
       } else {
           Log.d("IOT Not Connected")
           }
   }
   ```

Result Log :

> W/AWSIotMqttManager: connection is Lost
>
> Subscription error :com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Client error
>   when subscribing.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using `AWSMobileClient`. Perhaps you did not initialize the mobile client instance prior to using the IOT client? The details are outlined in the following [documentation](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/sdk/android/authentication).